# egui epaint loading image - dimensions problem

Tags: rust, egui

I am getting an image error that I'm guessing is dimension-related, since the left and right change whenever I change the image loading size variables. The program compiles but crashes on start.

This is my code, I'm inserting a PNG image into an existing Grid. [apologies for the verbose :: syntax, I use it while I'm learning a library]

```
use std::include_bytes;

const ICONB: &[u8; 3860] = include_bytes!("2.png");

(.. egui boilerplate ..)

impl eframe::App for MyApp {
  fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, _frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
    egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
      egui::Grid::new("")
        .striped(true)
        .show(ui, |ui| {
            ui.label("name");
            ui.add(egui::Image::new(
                egui::TextureId::from(
                    &egui::Context::load_texture(
                        &ctx,
                        "",
                        egui::ColorImage::from_rgba_unmultiplied(
                            [109usize, 462usize], //those are factual dimensions
                            ICONB
                        ),
                        egui::TextureFilter::Linear
                    )
                ), [109.0, 462.0]
            ));
```

Backtrace:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `201432`,
 right: `3860`', /home/tommy/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/epaint-0.19.0/src/image.rs:96:9
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/ca122c7ebb3ab50149c9d3d24ddb59c252b32272/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/ca122c7ebb3ab50149c9d3d24ddb59c252b32272/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   2: core::panicking::assert_failed_inner
   3: core::panicking::assert_failed
   4: epaint::image::ColorImage::from_rgba_unmultiplied
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
   7: egui::ui::Ui::allocate_ui_at_rect
   8: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}
   9: egui::containers::frame::Frame::show
  10: egui::containers::panel::CentralPanel::show
  11: <win::MyApp as eframe::epi::App>::update
  12: eframe::native::epi_integration::EpiIntegration::update
  13: <eframe::native::run::glow_integration::GlowWinitApp as eframe::native::run::WinitApp>::paint
  14: eframe::native::run::run_and_return::{{closure}}
  15: winit::platform_impl::platform::x11::EventLoop<T>::run_return::single_iteration
  16: winit::platform_impl::platform::x11::EventLoop<T>::run_return
  17: eframe::native::run::run_and_return
  18: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
  19: eframe::native::run::glow_integration::run_glow
  20: eframe::run_native
  21: win::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

That's the source code of `epaint`'s `from_rgba_unmultiplied` that fails:

```
pub fn from_rgba_unmultiplied(size: [usize; 2], rgba: &[u8]) -> Self {
        assert_eq!(size[0] * size[1] * 4, rgba.len());
        let pixels = rgba
            .chunks_exact(4)
            .map(|p| Color32::from_rgba_unmultiplied(p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]))
            .collect();
        Self { size, pixels }
    }
```

Can I load the image this way, how to understand the internals of loading an image better?

Follow-up issue: How can I implement rescaling in a fast way here?

Comment: The problem is that PNG doesn't store the byte values the way you're expecting it to, PNG doesn't store the raw RGBA values of each pixel in a neat row, it compresses them (Reducible on YouTube has a [great video explaining how PNG works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFUYNoFRHQI)), so you can't simply hand the raw bytes over to `from_rgba_unmultiplied` since the bytes aren't RGBA. You'll need to either use a image format that does store the bytes like that, or use a crate like [image](https://crates.io/crates/image) to get the raw RGBA bytes from your PNG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from_rgba_unmultiplied()` function that is panicking expects raw RGBA data, but you're passing in PNG-encoded image data. The PNG format compresses the image data, which is why the size is off and the assert fails.

To fix this, you need to decode the PNG data into raw RGBA before passing it to `from_rgba_unmultiplied()`. The [documentation for that function](https://docs.rs/epaint/0.19.0/epaint/image/struct.ColorImage.html#method.from_rgba_unmultiplied) shows exactly how to do that, with the help of the `image` crate:

```rust
fn load_image_from_memory(image_data: &[u8]) -> Result<ColorImage, image::ImageError> {
    let image = image::load_from_memory(image_data)?;
    let size = [image.width() as _, image.height() as _];
    let image_buffer = image.to_rgba8();
    let pixels = image_buffer.as_flat_samples();
    Ok(ColorImage::from_rgba_unmultiplied(
        size,
        pixels.as_slice(),
    ))
}
```